# LTC4365 Over/Under voltage setpoints

Tags: comparator

I built the over and under voltage protection circuit based on the LTC4365 from the May 2017 QST page 32.  Works ok.  The LTC4365 uses an external resistor voltage divider to set the over and under voltage set points. In studying the block diagram, I don't understand why the over voltage (OV) external voltage from the external divider circuit is LOWER than the under voltage (UV) value from the external voltage divider.

The block diagram shows that the OV and UV inputs go to separate comparators with the other input of each comparator going to +0.5V.

How is the external voltage from the external divider circuit is LOWER than the under voltage (UV) value from the external voltage divider?

he LTC4365 data sheet is [here](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/4365fa.pdf)

Comment: Take a close look at the comparators.  Note which input is connected to the 0.5V reference.  They are reversed.

Answer (score 1):

The [datasheet for the LTC4365](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/4365fa.pdf) includes a partial diagram of the internal circuitry.

Look at the connections behind the UV (under voltage) and OV (over voltage) pins.  Each input has a comparator that uses 0.5V as a reference.

The UV compares its input to 0.5V and triggers if the result is lower than 0.5V.

The OV compares its input to 0.5V and triggers if the result is over 0.5V.

So, in normal conditions, you want OV less than 0.5V and UV more than 0.5V.  This explains why OV is lower than UV.

Linear uses a single voltage divider with two taps to provide the UV and OV signals from Vin.  This saves you one resistor and some tracks.  It makes the calculations for the divide a tiny bit more difficult, but not all that much.

---

For reference, the two diagrams from the datasheet.

Internal block diagram of the LTC4365:

[image]

Example circuit:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a very clear explanation.  Makes sense now.  Sorry I don't have the rep to up-vote your answer.